# Making sidebar respect header & footer

Tags: html, css

I've taken this bootstrap code for a simple sidebar:http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/simple-sidebar/

What I need is for this sidebar code to respect the footer and header in the following code:

HTML:
       
    
        
            
        
      
          
    
        
            Header Content

```
<!-- BEGIN: Page Content -->
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">
 <! -- BEGIN: Side Bar Navigation -->
 <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                <li class="sidebar-brand">
                    <a href="#">
                        Start Bootstrap
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Shortcuts</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Overview</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Events</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->
        <!-- END: Sidebar Navigation -->
    </div>
</div>
<!-- END: Page Content -->

<!-- BEGIN: Sticky Footer -->
<div id="footer_container">
    <div id="footer">
        Footer Content
    </div>
</div>
<!-- END: Sticky Footer -->
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/* Reset body padding and margins */
body { margin:0; padding:0; }

/* Make Header Sticky */
#header_container {
    background:#eee;
    border:1px solid #666;
    height:60px;
    left:0;
    position:fixed; 
    width:100%;
    top:0; 
}

#header{
line-height:60px;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:940px;
    text-align:center;
}

/* CSS for the content of page. I am giving top and bottom padding of 80px to make sure the header and footer do not overlap the content.*/
#container { 
    margin:0
        auto; overflow:
            auto; padding;0px 0
    width:940px; 
}
#content{

}

/* Make Footer Sticky */
#footer_container { 
    background:#eee;
    border:1px solid #666; 
    bottom:0; 
    height:60px; 
    left:0; 
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
}

#footer { 
    line-height:60px;
    margin:0 auto; 
    width:940px; 
    text-align:center;
}

/* BEGIN: SideBar Navigation Baare */
#wrapper {
    padding-left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled {
    padding-left: 250px;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    left: 250px;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -250px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: #000;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 250px;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
}

#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: -250px;
}

/* Sidebar Styles */

.sidebar-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
    text-indent: 20px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
    height: 65px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 60px;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
    color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: none;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    #wrapper {
        padding-left: 250px;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled {
        padding-left: 0;
    }

    #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 250px;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 0;
    }

    #page-content-wrapper {
        padding: 20px;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
        position: relative;
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: define "respect header and footer". Do you want it so they adjust so the sidebar can be present? or?

Comment: Yes! Sorry for not specifying -- I need the sidebar to line up(not over-flow) with both the header and footer. Oh, and I can't find the part of the sidebar that specifies how far from the left it is.